# Getting a count of intervals

Tags: c++, optimization, interval

The statement of the problem is there are 2 files, one has a set of intervals i.e. 0-10, 3-40, etc which may be repetitive. The second file has a set of numbers which are also repetitive. The exercise is to get a count of the intervals, a number in the 2nd file would fit into.

Intervals.txt

```
0 12
2 36
6 98
2 36
```

Numbers.txt

```
2
4
123
20
```

What I thought of as a  possible solution was keep a count of intervals when you populate a map of intervals. So if you encounter an interval 3-40 5 times, you keep the count as 5 so you don't try to populate a map 5 times with the same interval. How it helps downstream is, if a number is in a specific interval you can count its existence in 5 intervals. Secondly there is a map of found numbers in your previous iterations, so that you don't loop through the intervals again.

I have been told, by some random guy, that my implementation is ok but not what he desires. No further explanations. I have tried raking my brain but haven't got any further. Any pointers or help would be much appreciated. Any further clarifications, please ask.

```
void generateCounts(const string& fname1, const string& fname2)
{
    std::ifstream file(fname1.c_str());
    string line;
    map<int, pair<int, int> > extents;
    map<int, pair<int, int> >::iterator it;
    std::string left;
    std::string right;

    if(file.is_open())
    {
        while(file.good())
        {
            getline(file, line);
            string::size_type pos = line.find(' '); 
            left = line.substr(0, pos);
            right = line.substr((++pos));
            int ll = atoi(left);
            int up = atoi(right);
            it = extents.find(ll);
            if(it != extents.end()) 
            {
                if(it->second.first != up){
                    extents.insert(make_pair<const int, pair<int, int> >(ll, make_pair<int, int>(up, ++count)));
                }
                else{
                    it->second.second += 1 ;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                extents.insert(make_pair<const int, pair<int, int> >(ll, make_pair<int, int>(up, ++count)));
            }
            count = 0;
        }
    }
    fclose(inp_file);

    std::ifstream file1(fname2.c_str());
    map<int, int> found;
    map<int, int>::iterator it1;
    string str;
    if(file1.is_open())
    {
        while(file1.good())
        {
            count = 0;
            getline(file1, str);
            if(str.empty()) continue;
            int var = atoi(str.c_str());
            it1 = found.find(var);
            if (it1 == found.end())
            {
                for(it = extents.begin(); it != extents.end(); ++it)
                {
                    if((var >= it->first ) && (var <= it->second.first))
                    {
                           count += it->second.second ;
                    }
                }
                found.insert(make_pair(var, count));
            }
            else
                count = it1->second;

            cout << count << "\n";
            str.clear();
    }
    file1.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

OK. Since this is homework I am going to limit my points to hints (I may add more in a week or so).

1. Why are you doing this?

   ```
   if(file.is_open())
   ```
2. This is an anti-pattern (in every language not just C++):
   Remember the eof (part of not being good) does not happen until you read past the end of line.

   Lots of examples on SO (go look it up).

   ```
       while(file.good())
       {
           getline(file, line);
   ```
3. You are doing too much work here:

   There is an easy way to read integers from a stream.  Lots of examples on SO (go look it up).

   ```
       getline(file, line);
       string::size_type pos = line.find(' '); 
       left = line.substr(0, pos);
       right = line.substr((++pos));   // Also this is wrong if no space was found.
       int ll = atoi(left);
       int up = atoi(right);
   ```
4. Why do a 2-phase compare?

   ```
       if(it != extents.end()) 
       {
           if(it->second.first != up){
               extents.insert(make_pair<const int, pair<int, int> >(ll, make_pair<int, int>(up, ++count)));
           }
           else{
               it->second.second += 1 ;
           }
       }
       else
       {
           extents.insert(make_pair<const int, pair<int, int> >(ll, make_pair<int, int>(up, ++count)));
       }
   ```

   If you make the **key** `std::pair&lt;left, right&gt;` then you only need to do one test. Not this complicated mess. It also makes more sense to keep the left and right together.
5. Don't do this: (see [Implementation using fstream failed evaluation](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/540/507))

   ```
   fclose(inp_file);
   ```

   Same comments about the second loop:

   This is not wrong. But when I compare a number against two others of a range I put the value that is being tested for inclusion in the range in the middle of the comparison. I personally find it nicer to read this way:

   ```
    if((var >= it->first ) && (var <= it->second.first))

    // I prefer

    if ((it->first <= var) && (var <= it->second.first))
   ```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but this ain't any homework, to make it clear.

Comment: OK. Then I will add more explanation tomorrow. But I will give you a chance to do some self learning.

Comment: 3)-> There is always going to be a space. That is the input. 4)-> There maybe the same starting first limit, but not necessarily the upper limit would be the same. e.g. 0 89 isn't the same as 0 56. Other points seems reasonable.

Comment: @DumbCoder: 3) Yes. There is still a much better way built into the language io libraries (hint: atoi() is old school C). 4) Yes exactly why the **key** should be `std::pair<left, right>` so the find() can find an exact mach without you doing extra work. ie the map is `std::map<std::pair<left, right>, count>`