# Parsing text file in C++

Tags: c++, parsing

I have a text file that contains `name`, `age`, `salary`, `hoursWorked`, `randomText` and are filled with different delimiters.

Text file:

```
susan:25-2600,28[asd]
mary:21-2200,38[asd]
john:23-3400,46[asd]
```

Instead of breaking them into individual strings using the code shown below:

```
string name,age,salary,hoursWorked,randomText;
ifstream readFile("textfile.txt");

while(getline(readFile,line))   {
    stringstream iss(line);
    getline(iss, name, ':');
    getline(iss, age, '-');
    getline(iss, salary, ',');
    getline(iss, hoursWorked, '[');
    getline(iss, randomText, ']');
}
readFile.close();
```

What are some better strategies other than coding it this way?

**Side note**

I declared all the variables to strings because of the `getline()` method.

Answer (score 15):

I would create a class and define an input operator:

```
struct Person
{
    std::string name;
    std::string age;
    std::string salary;
    std::string hoursWorked;
    std::string randomText;

    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& str, Person& data)
    {
        std::string line;
        Person tmp;
        if (std::getline(str,line))
        {
            std::stringstream iss(line);
            if ( std::getline(iss, tmp.name, ':')        && 
                 std::getline(iss, tmp.age, '-')         &&
                 std::getline(iss, tmp.salary, ',')      &&
                 std::getline(iss, tmp.hoursWorked, '[') &&
                 std::getline(iss, tmp.randomText, ']'))
             {
                 /* OK: All read operations worked */
                 data.swap(tmp);  // C++03 as this answer was written a long time ago.
             }
             else
             {
                 // One operation failed.
                 // So set the state on the main stream
                 // to indicate failure.
                 str.setstate(std::ios::failbit);
             }
        }
        return str;
    }
    void swap(Person& other) throws() // C++03 as this answer was written a long time ago.
    {
        swap(name,        other.name);
        swap(age,         other.age);
        swap(salary,      other.salary);
        swap(hoursWorked, other.hoursWorked);
        swap(randomText,  other.randomText)
    }
};
```

Now your code looks like this:

```
Person   data;
while(readFile >> data)
{
    // Do Stuff
}
```

PS. I noticed you were using `string` and `ifstream` without the `std::`. This suggests you have `using namespace std;` in your code. Please don't do that. see [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/14065)

Don't explictly `close()` a file unless you are going to check that it worked (or are going the re-open). Prefer to let the destructor do the closing (that way it is exception safe). See: [My C++ code involving an fstream failed review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/540/507)

Comment: In the operator>> definition I needed to add the class before the member variables (e.g. data.name, data.age) in the getline calls for this to compile.

Comment: @user39469: Sorry. Fixed.

Comment: Nice. The only thing I would change: I would use a local `Person tmp;` instance, and in the `if` code block (the "OK: All read operations worked" part) I would write `data = std::move(tmp);` (or `std::swap(data, tmp);`).. This way, you avoid the case when the stream doesn't actually contain a valid person (in that case, if one of the getline calls fails, `data` will not be partially filled with garbage).